# How to decrypt and copy home folder from laptop to external hard drive through live usb GUI?

Tags: encryption, gui, elementary-os

Everything was working alright until just two days ago when I decided to set the default brightness level using the instructions in https://askubuntu.com/questions/66751/how-do-i-set-default-display-brightness and later installing xSwipe touchpad driver following the instructions in http://www.elementarynow.com/multitouch-trackpads-luna/

No problems occurred on reboot after setting the default brightness level. However, as I installed XSwipe and reached the reboot stage according to the instructions in the webpage above, my laptop loaded with black screen and no GUI for awhile. I reboot and pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to look at the code interface. The first line of the code interface wrote

```
Error "[drm:cpt_serr_int_handler] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun"
```

When I switch back to the GUI with the 'E' logo, it showed “Disk drive for dev/mapper/cryptswap 1 is not ready yet or not present”

I am still able to use my laptop via the GUI of a live USB stick but cannot access files in home directory. I want to retrieve my files and data first before doing anything as I have dissertation work on this laptop. I can't seem to move or copy files because the `chmod` command says I am not allowed to do so even though I have already set terminal to root privileges.

Comment: It would be very useful if you post which Elementary OS version are you using and the output of the following command in a live USB system running in your laptop. `sudo lvdisplay`

Comment: @MauricioLópez

I am using elementary OS Freya 3.0

The output for sudo lvdisplay is:

No volume groups found

Answer (score 1):

Elementary OS is Ubuntu based so [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/) how-to should work (check the Recovering from a LiveCD section.)